# SublimeCodeIntel Autocomplete Fails with Pandas and Numpy

Tags: python, autocomplete, pandas, sublimetext3, sublimecodeintel

I'm trying and failing to get autocomplete working with python in Sublime Text 3.  Sublimecodeintel is recommended on multiple blogs and 'set up' guides.  When it works, it's great, but I can't get it to work with numpy or pandas, the two packages I use most.

Set up:
Mac OS X 10.9.4
I have installed python 2.7, numpy and pandas using Homebrew.
I am using sublime text 3, and installed sublimecodeintel using package manager.

An example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure() # autocomplete and tooltips works fine.

data = pd.read_csv('file.csv') # no autocomplete or tooltips.
```

Autocomplete options and tooltips are accesses in the 'plt' case first after the '.', then again when I start writing in the parentheses.  Nothing happens in the 'pd' case.

I haven't been able to find any documentation or previous questions about this. Is there something I've missed in the set up?  Is something missing from my config path?  Why isn't autocomplete working with my packages!?

config file and codintel.log follow...

Many thanks in advance.

My sublimecodeintel config file:

```
{
    "Python": {
        "python": '/usr/local/bin/python',
        "pythonExtraPaths": [
            "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages",
            "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/",
            "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/",
            "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages",
            "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
        ]
    }
}
```

Output in codintel.log:

```
+ Info: processing `Python': please wait...
New env with catalogs for 'Python': PyWin32
Updating indexes for 'Python'... The first time this can take a while.
scan_purelang: path: '/Users/oscarbranson/UCDrive/Projects/APT/MassSpectrum/APT_MS_autorange.py' lang: Python
Python Syntax Error in '/Users/oscarbranson/UCDrive/Projects/APT/MassSpectrum/APT_MS_autorange.py': invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 9)
Doing CodeIntel for 'Python' (hold on)...
eval 'plt' at APT_MS_autorange.py#9  <Trigger 'python-complete-object-members' at 168 (explicit)>
start scope is (<Element 'scope' at 0x1066bdf50>, [])
find 'plt ...' starting at (<Element 'scope' at 0x1066bdf50>, []):
is blob 'matplotlib.pyplot' from <Python curdirlib>? no
is blob 'matplotlib.pyplot' from <Python extradirslib>? yes
imports:: setting reldirlib to: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/matplotlib'
is 'plt' accessible on (<Element 'scope' at 0x1066bdf50>, [])? yes: <Element 'scope' at 0x1066aa7d0>
'plt' is <Element 'scope' at 0x1066aa7d0> on (<Element 'scope' at 0x1066aa7d0>, [])
is blob '__future__' from <Python reldirlib>? no
is blob '__future__' from <Python curdirlib>? no
is blob '__future__' from <Python extradirslib>? no
is blob '__future__' from <Python envlib>? no
is blob '__future__' from <Python sitelib>? no
is blob '__future__' from <Python cataloglib: PyWin32>? no
is blob '__future__' from <python-2.7 stdlib>? yes
#... big list here ...

done eval: success
Done 'Python' CodeIntel! Full CodeIntel took 10ms

Autocomplete called (Python) [calltips]
Updating indexes for 'Python'... The first time this can take a while.
scan_purelang: path: '/Users/oscarbranson/UCDrive/Projects/APT/MassSpectrum/APT_MS_autorange.py' lang: Python
Python Syntax Error in '/Users/oscarbranson/UCDrive/Projects/APT/MassSpectrum/APT_MS_autorange.py': invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 11)
Doing CodeIntel for 'Python' (hold on)...
eval 'pd' at APT_MS_autorange.py#27  <Trigger 'python-complete-object-members' at 500 (explicit)>
start scope is (<Element 'scope' at 0x107050de8>, [])
find 'pd ...' starting at (<Element 'scope' at 0x107050de8>, []):
is blob 'pandas' from <Python curdirlib>? no
is blob 'pandas' from <Python extradirslib>? yes
scan_purelang: path: '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py' lang: Python
# ... big list here ...
done eval: success
Done 'Python' CodeIntel! Full CodeIntel took 411ms
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to recommend SublimeCodeIntel, despite random hiccups like this, until I discovered [`Anaconda`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Anaconda). Once you set it up (a very brief process), it just works. There's no database to initialize or get corrupted, it automatically discovers when you've added new packages, it's very unobtrusive running in the background... I can't say enough good things about it. It uses the JEDI autocompletion module, among other things, and is fast and accurate. It automatically determines what type variables are, and fills in the completions with the appropriate methods and classes that can be called on it. You can have it do parameter completion as well, but that got a little annoying for me, so I turned it off. One thing it can't do is method chaining, but nothing's perfect. It also includes modules for code complexity checking and linting, which is fine, but I don't need it, and only want to lint when I want to lint, so I turned that off as well.

I'd highly recommend giving it a try. Aside from the method chaining, I've been very happy with it, and haven't gone back. One cool thing you can do is assign different values to the `"python_interpreter"` setting in your project files, so you can easily use virtualenvs, or (like I do) have one project open for Python 2 coding, and another for Python 3.

BTW, I'm not the developer, and have no connection to him/her :)

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Anaconda looks great, but the lack of method chaining really irks... I work a lot with pandas dataframes and multi-panelled plots.  This means that autocomplete doesn't work ~1/3 of the time with my Dataframe of Axes objects... any suggestions?

Comment: @user3851407 not really. Autocomplete works fine with variables, as (I assume) Anaconda keeps track of its type and autocompletes the classes/methods that are relevant. The problem with autocompleting chained methods is that you'd have to eval each method, determine the output, find its type, and then autocomplete the appropriate items. With large DFs, numpy arrays, etc. this could take quite a bit of time, especially with complex transformations.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think I misunderstood 'method chaining' to mean 'working with variables'.  I thought that Anaconda wasn't working with my variables, when it turns out the autocomplete was just being _really_ slow (2-5 seconds after I type).  Is this normal (i7 macbook pro retina)?  I assume not... if not, any ideas on how to speed it up? Google has proved unfruitful.

Comment: @user3851407 that's strange, autocomplete is nearly instantaneous for me, both on my i7 iMac from a few years ago, and my dual-core i5 Win8 laptop at work. Are your files gigantic? Also, do you have autocomplete on dot `.` set? In your user preferences, set `"autocomplete_triggers": [{"characters": ".", "selector": "source"}]` (or source.python, if you want) and the autocomplete menu will come up every time you type a dot (period, full stop, whatever).

Comment: Yep - got the "." trigger set up, but when I type a "." I get a list of autocomplete words from the whole document, then after 2-5 seconds the Anaconda autocomplete kicks in, and I get the python completions I'm expecting.  Weird!  Wonder what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: @user3851407 unfortunately, patience is what's needed. Try disabling all of your plugins except Anaconda, and see if the timing improves. If it does, you'll just have to start reactivating them one at a time to see which one is interfering. The other thing you can do is make sure you're running the latest build of Sublime, which is currently 3065.